# PostgreSQL - suggestions for building smarter queries?

Tags: sql, postgresql, express, knex.js

I'm new to backend dev and building a little social media app and I'm trying to understand how to build smarter queries for my Postgres. I'm using Express and Knex.

Suppose I have three tables: `users`, `posts` and `likes`. The `likes` table will have columns for `user_id` and `post_id` which reference the `users` and `posts` tables respectively.

When I run my app, I first query the db for posts and I get my list of posts. For each post, I'll need to query the `likes` table using the post_id to see if it has any Likes and if so, I'll get the like_id and user_id. Now, suppose I want the full user object, I now need to query the users table with the user_id to grab the user object.

My question is, is there a smarter / correct way to do these kinds of daisy-chain queries where you query one table for an ID so you can use it to query another table to get another ID, and so on? I feel like I'm doing it totally inefficiently but maybe that's just the way it's done?

Here's my query to get posts if it helps:

```
// server.js
app.get('/api/posts/get', (req, res) => posts.getPostData(req, res, db));

// imported get function
export const getPostData = (req, res, db) => {
  db.select('*')
    .from('posts')
    .then(items => {
      if (items.length) {
        res.json(items);
      } else {
        res.json({ dataExists: 'false' });
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).json({ dbError: err });
    });
};
```

Comment: Yes; the keyword you are looking for is *join*. Even if you use an ORM, it is important to understand SQL.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks Laurenz. I am very new to SQL and just learning how to write queries. I'm taking a Linked-In Learning course on PostgreSQL now.

Comment: I understand, and I think your question is good, and your feeling that this can be done better doesn't deceive you. I just cannot answer the question since I don't know Express and Knex.